# Different ways to perform retry task

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, completable-future

There is a very straightforward way to perform retry task using `while` loop:

```
    public <T> T runRetryTask(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        T taskExecutionResult = null;
        while (currentTime < expectedEndTime) {
            try {
                taskExecutionResult = supplier.get();
                if (taskExecutionResult != null) return taskExecutionResult;
                Thread.sleep( waitTime );
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return taskExecutionResult;
    }
```

I figured there is another way to perform such retry task using `ScheduledFuture` and `CompletableFuture`:

```
    public <T> T runRetryTask(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        CompletableFuture<T> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {

            T taskExecutionResult = supplier.get();
            if (taskExecutionResult != null || currentTime > expectedEndTime)
                completableFuture.complete(taskExecutionResult);
        }, 0, totalTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        completableFuture.whenComplete((result, throwable) () -> {
            scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
        });
        return completableFuture;
    }
```

Are there any advantages of using the second approach?

Comment: Yes, the 2nd approach doesn't swallow an exception.

Comment: Depending on you use case you might want to use resilicen4j's Retry facility: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry